# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletMapping;

Tags: spring-boot

```
    Maven Dependencies    

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

index.jsp page


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Application working</h3>
</body>
</html>

spring controller


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class SSOAppController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public  String indexPage() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Exception while running application on server:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletMapping;
    org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:180)
    org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:145)
    org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

Comment: In my Spring boot application, I have one controller class and one intex.jsp page. I already mapped view in application.properties file. When I run this application, I get this error. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Add following properties to your pom.xml and build,

**Note: Update the versions according to your environment.**

```
<properties>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.81</tomcat.version>
        <servlet-api.version>3.0.1</servlet-api.version>
    </properties>
```